# Identify and drop overlapped rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data in CSV:

```
Person_A,Person_B,date_time,duration 
177542,923164,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,10
966573,923134,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,4
966568,923135,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,12 
971582,923189,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,30
971582,923189,2021-08-01 00:10:00.000,30 
971582,923189,2021-08-01 00:20:00.000,30
```

I'm trying to identify the overlapped rows, store them in a separate dataframe and remove the overlapped rows from original dataframe.
In my scenario last three rows are overlapped between person A **971582** and person B **923189**, I have to keep the first overlapped row and discard the remaining

```
Desired output:
Person_A,Person_B,date_time,duration 
177542,923164,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,10
966573,923134,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,4
966568,923135,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,12
971582,923189,2021-08-01 00:00:00.000,30
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapped rows? What overlaps?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LchFgQIries&ab_channel=KnowledgeBase

tried this but faced errors with his solution

Comment: Time is overlapping in my case.

Comment: Sorry, I will not go and watch a youtube video. Please add relevant code that you've tried.

Comment: So you mean that if the last row has a date_time of "2021-08-01 02:00:00", it should be included in the result?

Comment: Yes, it should be included, actually what happening here is, that in my sample 3rd last row a started at date_time 2021-08-01 00:00:00.000 and its duration is 30 mins. What I want in the results is there should be no other record with date_time in this interval date_time+dauration (2021-08-01 00:00:00.000+30) for the same person A and B. if there are any records for the same person A & B found, that have date_time in this interval they should be discarded.

Comment: You should update your question with more details on what you mean by "overlapping rows", with the explanation about time overlaps and the relevant columns. Both current answers get your suggested result, but don't use your reasoning. Any other example would probably fail with these two answers.

Comment: Also: what should happen if there is a row with `971582,923189,2021-08-01 00:40:00.000,30`? It doesn't overlap with the first two `971582,923189` rows, but it does overlap with the last one. That last one, however, overlaps with the first and second one. Should the overlaps be additive, so that all but the first row get discarded. Or should the removal go first, so that the second and third row of `971582,923189` are discarded because of their overlap with the first row, and then the new row with time `00:400:00.000` gets to stay as well?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, I guess this should work. This doesn't consider "date_time" and "duration".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv') 
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Person_A', 'Person_B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `duplicated()` and `where()` methods to achieve what you want.

To store the duplicated data in a new dataframe, you can do

```
dupe_df = df.where(df.duplicated(keep="first")).dropna()
```

The `keep` argument allows you to specify whether you want to keep the first or last entry of duplicate rows.

To remove duplicated rows from the original dataframe, simply use

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=["Person_A", "Person_B"], keep="first", inplace=True)
```